# Calling Python in Fortran

Tags: python, fortran

I am learning Python; and will like to call some Python script from Fortran(will call `py2f`) (those will mostly do some type of logging etc.). My main code is still in Fortran.

While the opposite scenario (calling Fortran from Python; using `f2py`) is fairly common, I have not found much about `py2f`. One suggestion is to use cython, so, essentially to make py2C and the call it from Fortran.

The other thing I can think of is to `call execute_command_line` (I have not tried this yet, tried `call system` though.).

I don't think `py2f` is rare, I just want to know which is the standard and better practice: Cython or `call execute_command_line`? Or is something else?

Comment: I think calling Python from Fortran is rare, whether using `py2f` or not.  Let's see what answers to your question are forthcoming.

Comment: If you need to pass some data in memory (not in data files) you cannot use execute_command_line.

Comment: I use `execute_command_line`, using txt files to pass information. Of course, I mainly use python for plotting (matplotlib), so it's usually after all the computation stuff is over.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [embedded Python in C](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html) an then from the c interphase try to communicate with [Fortran using the standard c bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/fortran-iso-c-binding/info).

I'm dealing with the same problem right now so that's all i can help you with. Sorry